# Sphinx WARNING: source src1: skipped 10 document(s) with zero/NULL ids

Tags: php, mysql, linux, terminal, sphinx

I have a problem.

When I typed /usr/local/bin/indexer --all --config /usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf to terminal , The output was like that :

> Sphinx 2.0.8-release (r3831)
>
> Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
>
> Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc
>   (http://sphinxsearch.com)
>
> using config file '/usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf'...
>
> indexing index 'search'...
>
> WARNING: source src1: skipped 10 document(s) with zero/NULL ids
>
> collected 0 docs, 0.0 MB
>
> total 0 docs, 0 bytes
>
> total 0.006 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
>
> total 1 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
>
> total 5 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg

Here is my sphinx.conf:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2c1b32be9c7dd61bc24f

So do you think , what the problem is ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very first column in your `sql_query` is ALWAYS taken as the document-ID.

```
sql_query      = SELECT u.username, a.user_id, a.id, ....
```

In your query, is u.username really a completely unique unsigned 32bit integer?

Answer (score 2):

as

```
GROUP BY a.id
```

you probably just write

```
sql_query      = SELECT a.id, u.username, a.user_id,  ....
```

Comment: I'm sorry , vote up requires 15 reputations but i have only 7 :/